# iOS - Push notification and distance tracking in fitness app

Tags: ios, push-notification, reset

First of all, I'm a very beginner at iOS and I'm working on my first iOS app ever for my thesis. (I'm using Parse.com for my database) I'm developing a fitness app(iOS) that tracks user's walked/run distance everyday. My app can already run in background to keep tracking the distance even when users are not playing on the app. Anyway, these are a few problems I have...

1. I want my app to send push notification to users when they've reached their distance goal in everyday, how do i do it? I guess this is possible according to some apps/games I have used, for example Candy Crush that sends me notification when my hearts is full again, or Ground Miles that alarms me when I've reached every 1,000 steps. Or I'm just getting this wrong? If yes, any suggestion?
2. I want to send the distance walked data in that day to database and reset the distance walked value shown in app back to 0km every midnight, so that I can show users how far they've completed each day. How do I reset the distance value shown? and how do I send the data to my database at specific time or in a way that suits my function mentioned above? Right now I'm saving it to my database using saveEventually function in my applicationDidEnterBackground method, which I don't think is a right way to do it.

---

Please give me some suggestion for this :) I've already been looking on many pages and sites but don't seem to get the answer I want. I'd appreciate every comments and thank you so much in advance!

Aimme :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse has Push Notifications, look into their documentation for that. You will also need to set up some script (parse also has this) when a user updates their location. (i.e. check if they reached their goal then send push if true)
2. Add a date attribute/column when you update the parse database for location or distance walked. On your app, when you grab data only grab data for that date (or whatever days you need) with a filter, or just filter it app side yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1) When you detect a limit has been reached use UIApplication:presentLocalNotificationNow (if your app is in the background, if its in the foreground just present an alert view, its daft to post a notification if your app is in the foreground at that time)

2) You can't schedule your app to run at midnight, nor schedule your app to save data at a particular time. The only chances you will have to reset the distance and save data is if the user runs the app or if you get a location update from the OS. Everytime the app runs you'll have to see what the current date/time is and save it, then next time you run, if its the first time the app is running that day then you know you have to reset the count to 0.
You should be saving your data to the database every time the location has changed (make sure to filter out insignification location changes)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use cloud code for that one.  If you're storing the data at some point, you could implement an aftersave function that calculates whether or not the user achieved their goal.  Then, if they have you can send a push notification directly from parse's servers.